# Python Numpy Poisson regression producing bad numbers

Tags: python, numpy, regression, least-squares, poisson

I would like to use Poisson regression to model football matches. I am trying to fit attack and defence ratings to each team based on past results. So say I have a set of results like this:

```
A v B 2 0
B v A 2 1
A v B 1 1
```

The number of goals each team scores goes into a vector like this:

```
Y = numpy.array([2,0.001,2,1,1,1]) #0.001 will become clear soon
```

I'm trying to fit the home and away defence ratings in a vector `B` such that `Y = exp(X*B)` where X is a matrix representing the results of the games.

The vector `B` is in the form:

```
B = [A_home_attack,
 A_home_defence,
 B_home_attack,
 B_home_defence,
 A_away_attack,
 A_away_defence,
 B_away_attack,
 B_away_defence]
```

From the above table of results the matrix X must look like this:

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1]
[0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0]
[0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1]
[0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0]
```

Now since the left-hand-side of the model equation above is in terms of e^x I take logarithms of the vector `Y` (hence entering 0 as 0.001, log(0) is not defined).

Here is my Python implementation of the algorithm stated above:

```
import numpy

Y = numpy.array([2,0.001, 2,1,1,1])
X = numpy.matrix([ [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1], [0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0], [0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0],  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1], [0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0]])
logY = numpy.log(Y)
beta = numpy.linalg.lstsq(X,logY)
print beta[0]

print "A %.2f v %.2f B" % ( beta[0][0] - beta[0][7], beta[0][6] - beta[0][1] )
```

The output of the above is:

```
[  1.73286795e-01   1.72693882e+00   3.46573590e-01  -1.11022302e-16
1.45089809e-16  -3.46573590e-01  -1.72693882e+00  -1.73286795e-01]

 A 0.35 v -3.45 B
```

The numbers `beta[0][0] - beta[0][7]` and `beta[0][6] - beta[0][1]` represent the expected number of goals for the home and away teams. These must be positive by definition so something has gone wrong.

If anyone could point out the error of my ways I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the response Y has a Poisson distribution, then the expected value of Y is equal to the model parameter mu, i.e. E[Y]=mu.

Now in a Poisson regression you model the log of the expected counts as a linear combination of unknown parameters, i.e. log( E[Y] ) = X * beta. This is a generalized linear model, where  the parameters beta are not necessarily all positive.

In order to obtain your fitted scores you need to take the exponential again, i.e. E[Y] = exp(X * beta).

```
import numpy

Y = numpy.array([2,0.001, 2,1,1,1])
X = numpy.matrix([ [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1], [0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0], [0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0],  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1], [0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0]])
logY = numpy.log(Y)
beta = numpy.linalg.lstsq(X,logY)[0]

print X
print beta
print numpy.exp( X.dot(beta) )
```

This produces:

```
[[ 1.41421356  0.03162278  2.          1.          1.41421356  0.03162278]]
```